# How can I use a std::map with std::weak_ptr as key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, weak-references, weak-ptr

How can I use `std::weak_ptr` as key for a `std::map` as shown in the following code?

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::map< std::weak_ptr<int>, bool > myMap;

    std::shared_ptr<int> sharedptr(new int(5));
    std::weak_ptr<int> weakptr = sharedptr;

    myMap[weakptr] = true;

    return 0;
}
```

The above program doesn't build and trying to compile it gives many error messages such as:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::tr1::weak_ptr<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(1885) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(124) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::tr1::weak_ptr<int>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\map(71) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::tr1::weak_ptr<int>
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree(451) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::tr1::weak_ptr<int>,
1>              _Ty=bool,
1>              _Pr=std::less<std::tr1::weak_ptr<int>>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tr1::weak_ptr<int>,bool>>,
1>              _Mfl=false
1>          ]
```

The problem occurs due to the following line:

```
myMap[weakptr] = true;
```

The error messages seem to be related to `operator<`. Do I need to define `operator<` for `weak_ptr`? Exactly, what operators need to be defined in order to use a data type as a key for a `std::map`?

(I should note that I have already defined `operator==` in the `std` namespace. Also, I plan to use a `weak_ptr` to a custom class type and not an `int`.)

Comment: Should pointers to distinct `int` objects with the same value be equal or different? I.e. how many elements should be present from `auto first = std::make_shared(5); auto second = std::make_shared(5); myMap[first] = true; myMap[second] = false;`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

C++11 provides appropriate mechanisms for comparisons of `std::weak_ptr`, namely: `std::owner_less`.

This should be the default for maps and sets.  If the C++ compiler you are using is having a hard time, try using `std::owner_less` if it is available.  If it is not available, you will need to provide a similar mechanism as `std::owner_less` so you can appropriately compare `std::weak_ptr` objects.

Comment: The final form would be `std::map<std::weak_ptr<T>, U, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<T>>>`

Answer (score 9):

As explained in [Jody Hagins' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12875833/2675154), you should use [`std::owner_less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/owner_less) as comparison function object of an associative container if you use a [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) as key. I'd like to expand on that answer by providing the following full solution for your code:

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::weak_ptr<int>, bool, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<int>>> myMap;

    std::shared_ptr<int> sharedptr(new int(5));
    std::weak_ptr<int> weakptr = sharedptr;

    myMap[weakptr] = true;

    return 0;
}
```

Since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) you can omit the template parameter for `owner_less`, resulting in shorter code as follows:

```
std::map<std::weak_ptr<int>, bool, std::owner_less<>> myMap;
```

And if you plan to use a `weak_ptr` to a custom class instead of an `int`, then you can simply replace the `int` by the name of your class as shown in [this example code on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3325ef858b626aa).

In general, apart from providing a proper comparison function (or overloading `operator<`) for a (custom) key type, nothing needs to be done for a `std::map`. Overloading `operator==` for the key type is not required.