# Is it safe to store a changing object in a stl set?

Tags: c++, stl

I want a container to store unique std::weak_ptrs. std:set requires operator<, presumably because it stores the items in a tree. My worry is if I implement operator< in the obvious way (destroyed ptr = null ptr < valid ptr) then this result can mutate after items are added to the container, which may break it.

Is this in fact safe? If not, any suggestions for a container?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a default std::less on my gcc for weak_ptrs

Comment: `operator<` seems not to be defined for `weak_ptr`, so `less` won't work.

Comment: Could it help? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/owner_less

Comment: @Sam: Oh, OK, in that case use `std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<T>>` as the predicate.

Comment: Cool thanks, owner_less looks perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `weak_ptr`s as keys unless you use a owner based comparison (against the value based one, that is not even defined for *weak_ptr*, for which trying to use the *operator<* results in an error).
The problem is that they can expire and the ordering of your containers (a `set` as well as a `map`) wouldn't be consistent anymore.

As correctly pointed out by Kerrek SB (forgive me, but the mobile app does not let me to correctly link users) and as you can read from my link in the comments, you can rely on `std::owner_less` starting from C++11.

A valid approach is to use a `set` defined as it follows:

```
std::set<std::weak_ptr<C>, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<C>>>
```

Note that `owner_less` can be less verbose, for it deduces the type automatically.

Keep in mind that this approach does not keep you from invoking the `expired` method while visiting the `set`, because it can still contains expired objects even if consistently ordered.

Also, note that there is a huge difference between an expired `weak_ptr` and an empty one, so the owner based comparison could be not so intuitively, even if expiration shouldn't affect it once used the approach above mentioned.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/owner_less) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875652/stdmap-with-stdweak-ptr-key) [links](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/owner_less/).

Answer (score 1):

user3159253 is correct. Found the full answer here:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1590.html

```
     weak_ptr::operator<
```

Since a weak_ptr can expire at any time, it is not possible to order weak pointers based on their value. Accessing the value of a deleted pointer invokes undefined behavior, and reinterpret_cast tricks are no good, either, as the same pointer value can be reused by the next new expression. Using p.lock().get() for ordering is similarly flawed, as this implies that the value of p < q may change when p or q expires. If p and q are members of a std::set, this will break its invariant.
The only practical alternative is to order weak pointers by the address of their control block, as the current specification effectively demands.

Comment: That paper is a nice find. For one thing, I expected the order of the weak pointers to be retained after expiration. TIL!