# How to identify a connection with websocketpp

Tags: c++, websocket

I have a piece of code that uses websocketpp to run a server. I would like to identify the different connections that come to the server. To do so it seems that the `websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl` should be used.

```
namespace websocketpp {

/// A handle to uniquely identify a connection.
/**
 * This type uniquely identifies a connection. It is implemented as a weak
 * pointer to the connection in question. This provides uniqueness across
 * multiple endpoints and ensures that IDs never conflict or run out.
 *
 * It is safe to make copies of this handle, store those copies in containers,
 * and use them from other threads.
 *
 * This handle can be upgraded to a full shared_ptr using
 * `endpoint::get_con_from_hdl()` from within a handler fired by the connection
 * that owns the handler.
 */
typedef lib::weak_ptr<void> connection_hdl;
```

But as you can see it is a `weak_ptr<void>` that I don't know how it can be compared with others.

I have a map with `websocketpp::connection_hdl` as index that when I try to see if has an existent index with:

```
std::map<websocketpp::connection_hdl, asio::ip::tcp::socket> active_connections;
if (active_connections.count(con->get_socket()) > 0) {}
```

The compiler complains with:

> error C2678:  binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Is there any way I can get the socket from the connection (the raw integer socket). If I can I could use that as an index and solve the problem.

Can you see any other way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You are using a weak_ptr as a key without using std::owner_less. More information: [How can I use a std::map with std::weak_ptr as key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875652/how-can-i-use-a-stdmap-with-stdweak-ptr-as-key)
2. In your example, you are using a socket as a key instead of a connection_hdl.

Solution:

```
std::map<websocketpp::connection_hdl, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket, std::owner_less<websocketpp::connection_hdl>> active_connections;
if (active_connections.count(con) > 0) {}
```

However, the map doesn't make that much sense: If you have the connection_hdl, you can get the socket of the connection with the get_socket() method. I have never used this method, but I think it should work? If you just want to store all open connections and their sockets, a std::vector containing the connection handles is probably better.